# Do man-made machines take natural Nitrogen out of the atmosphere and in turn cause global warming?

Tags: atmosphere, climate-change

I read in Wikipedia that, "Natural Nitrogen, Dinitrogen forms about 78% of Earth's atmosphere. Dinitrogen is the most abundant uncombined element in the atmosphere."

Do man-made machines destroy the natural Nitrogen, the extremely strong triple bond in elemental nitrogen (N≡N), turning natural Nitrogen into other compounds, molecules?

Does man-made fractional distillation, Nitrogen gas generators, and membranes take natural Nitrogen out of the atmosphere or ionosphere, causing global warming?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that using atmospheric nitrogen as a feedstock for industrial processes doesn't really affect the climate per se. It does mess with the environment (primarily through deposition of nitrogen fertiliser) but this is a separate issue.

The problem from a climate point of view, is that the process is virtually certain to emit a lot of greenhouse gasses (primarily CO2 from fossil fuel powered machinery)